# read multiple csv files and create 3D array in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have multiple csv files in a directory. How can I create a 3D array while reading them in R?

Here is what I tried:

```
temp <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
myfiles <- lapply(temp, read.delim)
```

This creates a list but I am not sure how to create 3D array from here. Any thoughts?

Comment: If your data is properly set up, you could do `array(unlist(myfiles), dim=c(dim(myfiles[[1]], length(myfiles))`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestion but it seems to be incomplete

Comment: Without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), that's about the best I can do.

Comment: Thanks, it works

Comment: For those of you, who will come here and fail at running the command above. Here is the working version ( a few closing brackets are missing):
`array(unlist(myfiles), dim=c(dim(myfiles[[1]]), length(myfiles)))`